# Set Time(0) Data Type in Sql Server to NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

I am currently in the process of moving an Access table to SQL Server. The access table uses the [Long Time](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-and-customize-date-and-time-formats-763b9b04-ccf8-46a8-9ee3-6d8f6fb9e2f8) format. I am moving the data from the Long Time into a [Time(0)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) format.

The Time(0) is defined as:

```
[timePosted] [time](0) NULL DEFAULT (NULL)
```

When I insert into the table through a pass through query, I check for Nulls in VBA:

```
IIf(IsNull(timePosted), " NULL ", "'" & rs!timePosted & "'")
```

The table has the data:

```
00:00:00
```

How do I insert a Null into a time field?

Comment: Why default `NULL` to `NULL` if it is already `NULL` by default? :-)

Comment: @Nicarus, because it wasn't defaulting to Null :(

Comment: But it was defaulting to `NULL` - the difference is that you were supplying it with a non-Null value... If you want to make a specific value NULL, you can do that with `NULLIF` or, if it is more complex, a `CASE` statement.

Comment: What is your full INSERT statement? How is the Time(0) column in the linked table shown in Access table design? Maybe Access doesn't really handle that datatype very well. What Access version do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is a little easier than expected.

The IsNull() function was evaluation to False. The reason for that was the field was empty and not null.

Checking IsNull and IsEmpty solved every problem I was having.

I also did not set it to the recordset field. I set it to a non existing variable.

Doh.